# Get Facebook email C# SDK -> Nested JSON

Tags: c#, facebook, json

i'm using Json to get information of facebook users to my app, but i need their email, it's possible?

i'm using this code:

```
var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)AccessToken.getclient().Get("me");
```

but i only can get id, name, first_name, link..., and I need the email user! how can i get it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need email permission, then you can read out the users mail

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions